# Multiplying brackets in $n(n+1)/2+n+1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Why does:

$$n(n+1)/2+n+1 = (n^2+3n+2)/2 $$

and not

$$ (n^2+2n+1)/2 $$

?

Additionally, why is:

$$(n^2+3n+2)/2 = ((n+1)(n+1)+1)/2$$

rather than:

$$((n+1)(n+1)+1n)/2$$

Comment: It stems from the fact that to add two fractions together, you should first make sure that they have the same denominator.  $\frac{a}{b} + \frac{c}{d} = \frac{ad + bc}{bd}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since

$$
\dfrac{n(n+1)}2+n+1=\dfrac{n^2+n}{2}+\dfrac{2(n+1)}2=\dfrac{n^2+n+2(n+1)}{2}=\ldots
$$

To add $\tfrac{A}{B}$ with some number $C$ you must have common denominators, i.e.

$$
\frac AB+C=\frac A{\color{royalblue}B}+\frac{BC}{\color{royalblue}B}=\frac{A+BC}B.
$$

Let's say that for some reason you forgot that rule. Then here's a way to come up with the solution. Let

$$
D=\dfrac{n(n+1)}2+n+1,
$$

then

$$
2D=n(n+1)+2(n+1).
$$

Dividin both sides by $2$ gives :

$$
D=\dfrac{n(n+1)+2(n+1)}{2}=\ldots
$$